# unable to start 'Docker for windows' on Azure Win 10 VM

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine, docker-engine

I just downloaded "Docker for Windows" from the Docker Hub website
https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

I am running an Azure VM with Windows 10 Pro N. The VM's size is 'Standard B2s (2 vcpus, 4 GB memory)'

I am getting the error below:
[image]

I read this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Is this issue due to VM size? If so, how do I install the version of Docker for this VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only certain Azure VMs support nested virtualization. This link shows which ones support it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu

Look for the machines with "***" in the "vCPU: Core" column as the article states:

***Hyper-threaded and capable of running nested virtualization

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it due to the VM size. While you want to install Docker engine in the Windows VM, you need to enable the virtualization in the VM. And for Azure VM, it means the appropriate sizes for the VM. See the steps that [enable nested virtualization in an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization). Then the Docker engine will work well in the VM.

Here is the example, the vm size is Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory), then the docker engine installs in it and works well. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: any link where i can get list of VM supported by nested virtualization?

Comment: @knowdotnet The link is already existing in the document. I provide you again [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu). Take a look at the explanation below the document.

Comment: i marked it as answer but this query is still open :  link where i can get list of VM supported by nested virtualization. The link you mentioned gives list of all VM only

Comment: @knowdotnet Do you see the description "***Hyper-threaded and capable of running nested virtualization" below the link? The size table shows the sizes that support the nested virtualization with the `***`.

Comment: Thanks, i overlooked!